# how to create new mysql db (clone current) from within rails app?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to clone current database, and assign it a new name. How to do this from within rails app?. Or maybe I need to run some bash `mysqldump -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db1 | mysql -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db2` ? if so, how to implement it (run from rails model)?. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not direct method to do this in Rails. MySQL mysqldump utility works best in these cases.

Comment: blame.. I hoped that this magic exists )). So the issue now is - how to run this command from within rails model (I need it to be a model:) ).

Comment: can I user `exec('ls ~')` ??

Comment: Why you want to make it in models? Will you run it too often?

Comment: Once a year, but I want to store all the logic in one model. It will be peaty hairy.

Comment: Ok, I find an solution here [Execute shell commands](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands)